# positioning correctly a big draw on the sheet

Tags: positioning

I'm trying to fit my drawing inside the sheet but there is a lot of space left over on the top of the sheet (compared to the bottom). How could I fit the drawing?

[image]

[image]

This is my code (it's really simple cause I'm just starting with Tikz):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Sigma demostration draw}
\author{}
\date{February 2021}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\clearpage

\begin{tikzpicture}
 % flecha
 [->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1.7cm,font=\scriptsize]
 % estilo circulo
 \tikzstyle{circulo}=[circle,fill=cyan,draw=none,text=black,draw=cyan!40, fill=cyan!10, very thick, minimum size=6mm]
 % estilo cuadrado
 \tikzstyle{cuadrado}=[rectangle,fill=blue,draw=none,text=black,draw=blue!40, fill=blue!10, very thick, minimum size=6mm]

% G1
\node[cuadrado] (g1_1) {$y_m$};
\node[circulo] (g1_2) [left of=g1_1] {$y_m$};
\node[circulo] (g1_3) [right of=g1_1] {$\neg y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_4) [above left of=g1_2] {$y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_6) [above right of=g1_3] {$\neg y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_8) [above right of=g1_2] {$y_m^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_9) [above left of=g1_3] {$\neg y_m^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_10) [above of=g1_8] {$y_m^1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_11) [above of=g1_9] {$\neg y_m^1$};

% G2
\node[cuadrado] (g2_1) [above = 3.5cm of g1_1] {$y_1$};
\node[circulo] (g2_2) [left of=g2_1] {$y_1$};
\node[circulo] (g2_3) [right of=g2_1] {$\neg y_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_4) [above left of=g2_2] {$y_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_6) [above right of=g2_3] {$\neg y_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_8) [above right of=g2_2] {$y_1^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_9) [above left of=g2_3] {$\neg y_1^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_10) [above of=g2_8] {$y_1^1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_11) [above of=g2_9] {$\neg y_1^1$};

% G3
\node[cuadrado] (g3_1) [above = 8.5cm of g1_1] {$x_n$};
\node[circulo] (g3_2) [left of=g3_1] {$x_n$};
\node[circulo] (g3_3) [right of=g3_1] {$\neg x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_4) [above left of=g3_2] {$x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_5) [below left of=g3_2] {$x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_6) [above right of=g3_3] {$\neg x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_7) [below right of=g3_3] {$\neg x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_8) [above right of=g3_2] {$x_m^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_9) [above left of=g3_3] {$\neg x_m^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_10) [above of=g3_8] {$x_m^1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_11) [above of=g3_9] {$\neg x_m^1$};

% G4
\node[cuadrado] (g4_1) [above = 13cm of g1_1] {$x_1$};
\node[circulo] (g4_2) [left of=g4_1] {$x_1$};
\node[circulo] (g4_3) [right of=g4_1] {$\neg x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_4) [above left of=g4_2] {$x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_5) [below left of=g4_2] {$x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_6) [above right of=g4_3] {$\neg x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_7) [below right of=g4_3] {$\neg x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_8) [above right of=g4_2] {$x_1^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_9) [above left of=g4_3] {$\neg x_1^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_10) [above of=g4_8] {$x_1^1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_11) [above of=g4_9] {$\neg x_1^1$};

% G10
\node[circulo] (g10_1) [below = 1cm of g1_1] {$u_0$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_2) [below left of=g10_1] {$u_0$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_3) [below right of=g10_1] {$u_0 \_ u_0^,$};
\node[circulo] (g10_4) [below of=g10_1] {$u_0^,$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_5) [below left of=g10_4] {$u_0^,$};
%\node[cuadrado] (g10_6) [below right of=g10_5] {$z$};
%\node[cuadrado] (g10_7) [left of=g10_6] {$z$};
%\node[cuadrado] (g10_8) [above of=g10_6] {$u_0^,$};
%\node[cuadrado] (g10_9) [above right of=g10_6] {$u_0^,$};
%\node[cuadrado] (g10_10) [right of=g10_6] {$u_0^,$};


\path   
% G1
    (g1_2) edge [below] node {k+1} (g1_1)
        edge [] node {n-1} (g1_4)
        edge [] node {1} (g1_8)
        edge [bend left] node {1} (g1_10)
    (g1_3) edge [below] node {k+1} (g1_1)
        edge [] node {n-1} (g1_6)
        edge [] node {1} (g1_9)
        edge [bend right] node {1} (g1_11)
% G2
    (g2_2) edge [below] node {k+1} (g2_1)
        edge [] node {n-1} (g2_4)
        edge [] node {1} (g2_8)
        edge [bend left] node {1} (g2_10)
    (g2_3) edge [below] node {k+1} (g2_1)
        edge [] node {n-1} (g2_6)
        edge [] node {1} (g2_9)
        edge [bend right] node {1} (g2_11)
% G3
    (g3_2) edge [below] node {k+1} (g3_1)
        edge [] node {n-1} (g3_4)
        edge [] node {1} (g3_5)
        edge [] node {1} (g3_8)
        edge [bend left] node {1} (g3_10)
    (g3_3) edge [below] node {k+1} (g3_1)
        edge [] node {n-1} (g3_6)
        edge [] node {1} (g3_7)
        edge [] node {1} (g3_9)
        edge [bend right] node {1} (g3_11)
% G4
    (g4_2) edge [below] node {k+1} (g4_1)
        edge [] node {n-1} (g4_4)
        edge [] node {1} (g4_5)
        edge [] node {1} (g4_8)
        edge [bend left] node {1} (g4_10)
    (g4_3) edge [below] node {k+1} (g4_1)
        edge [] node {n-1} (g4_6)
        edge [] node {1} (g4_7)
        edge [] node {1} (g4_9)
        edge [bend right] node {1} (g4_11)
        
% G10
    (g10_1) edge [] node {k+1} (g10_2)
            edge [] node {n} (g10_3)
    (g10_4) edge [] node {n+2} (g10_3)
            edge [] node {k} (g10_5)
%    (g10_5) edge [] node {r-u} (g10_6)
%    (g10_7) edge [] node {r} (g10_6)
%    (g10_8) edge [] node {r-u} (g10_6)
%    (g10_9) edge [] node {r-u} (g10_6)
%    (g10_10) edge [] node {r-u} (g10_6);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: PLease extend your code fragment to complete, compilable small document. Now it is impossible to test your code.

Comment: Sorry, this is my code: https://codeshare.io/501d9L

Comment: Please edit your question and provide in it all needed (and not more) code. Your link can become after while dead and others will not see, what is the problem.